# Comparing based on unique column values and set a flag based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, pandas-groupby

I'm very new to pandas and dataframe. I've previously used SQL. I've attached a table below:

```
    Sub     DOB         Groups      Mean Val  CheckVol
0   1112    1/1/1980    FirstVisit  6000      0
1   1121    2/2/1980    FirstVisit  6000      0
2   1138    3/3/1980    FirstVisit  6000      0
3   1227    4/4/1980    FirstVisit  6000      0
12  1443    1/1/1980    SecondVisit 5000      0
13  1443    2/2/1980    SecondVisit 5500      0
14  1481    3/3/1980    SecondVisit 6500      1
15  1482    4/4/1980    SecondVisit 5400      0
24  1483    2/2/1980    ThirdVisit  5400      0
25  1490    3/3/1980    ThirdVisit  5400      0
```

So what I want to do is grouping based on DOB as this is unique compare the mean val vs first visit. And if the second visit is larger than the first then check third visit and if third visit is smaller than first visit change the labels. So in the example table change groups in 14 to ThirdVisit and 25 to SecondVisit. I was thinking maybe creating a new column as a flag called checkVol in this case and case 14 will have a 1. This is what I have which is very wrong:

```
checkVol = df.groupby('DOB').apply(lambda r: r)
#df.set_index('DOB', inplace=True)
df['checkVol'] = users
```

Thank you for your help.

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, You can `groupby` the `DOB` column, then use transform on the `Mean Val` column with the condition you described. This will return a boolean column, so you just have to convert it to `int`:

```
df['CheckVol'] = df.groupby('DOB')['Mean Val'].transform(lambda x: x > x.iloc[0]).astype(int)

>>> df
     Sub       DOB       Groups  Mean Val  CheckVol
0   1112  1/1/1980   FirstVisit      6000         0
1   1121  2/2/1980   FirstVisit      6000         0
2   1138  3/3/1980   FirstVisit      6000         0
3   1227  4/4/1980   FirstVisit      6000         0
12  1443  1/1/1980  SecondVisit      5000         0
13  1443  2/2/1980  SecondVisit      5500         0
14  1481  3/3/1980  SecondVisit      6500         1
15  1482  4/4/1980  SecondVisit      5400         0
24  1483  2/2/1980   ThirdVisit      5400         0
25  1490  3/3/1980   ThirdVisit      5400         0
```